# Android app running above another app

Tags: android, sdk

I'm currently playing a very repetitive android game. I would use my programming skills to automate some in-game tasks :)

My idea is to write an application (BOT) that runs my game (GAME) and stay on top of it (something like a popup). BOT should offer a number of options to simulate a sequence of user touches in GAME.

Since I'm not an android developer I would like to know if such interaction is possible and what kind of object I could use to achieve such result. I think standard android app doesn't allow this kind of interaction.

Comment: You would need to draw over the app which requires this [permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW).